# Upgrade remains till the time phone is rebooted

Tags: android, upgrade, sideloading

I have an application, which I have made it as part of system apps.
I have an option to sideload the application and upgrade to next level and upgrade works fine.
But, when I reboot the device, Android points back to the system app and the upgrade is lost.

Any pointers on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: `I have made it as part of system apps`. Please tell how you did that. How that is possible.

Comment: Similar to other Android apps (ex: calendar, hangout, etc), I have placed the APK in my build and added .SO file in system lib.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand a word of this.

Comment: Application is part of system apps. I have the APK & SO file as part of system. Now, when I do a side loading, I see this problem.